# Gitlab Runner esta eliminando mi volumen

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Actualmente tengo un pipeline en Gitlab Ci. Dentro de mi Docker compose defino un volumen:

```
    services:
  mongo:
    container_name: report-svc-mongodb
    image: mongo:6.0
    # ports:
    #   - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    command: ['--auth']
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-vol:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
      # - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${MONGO_DATABASE}
```

y este es mi gitlab-ci.yml

```
    image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build  
     
  script:
  # Create a tag using the commit and the job ID
    - export TAG=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}-${CI_JOB_ID}

    # Login into the containers registryy
    - docker login $CI_REGISTRY -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
    # Build and push the real image
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:$TAG . 
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:$TAG

    # Retag and push the image to have a latest tag
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:$TAG $CI_REGISTRY/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest
  only:
    - develop

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    -  docker pull "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
    -  docker-compose pull
    -  docker-compose up -d
    -  docker-compose ps
  only:
    - develop
```

No entiendo por qué cuando el runner de Gitlab levanta mi aplicación también borra mi volumen que esta en la raíz de mi proyecto. Debería hacerlo de otra forma?

```
    Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/aX3Pcb7dt/0/agl/report-service/.git/
Checking out 56b93c59 as detached HEAD (ref is develop)...
Removing mongo-vol/
```